# Calling variable from JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

I read data from an XML file and store it in the variable `xml`.

Later I convert this into JSON format and save it in the variable `json`.

Following is JSON:

```
{
  'maven2-moduleset': {
    '$': {
      plugin: 'maven-plugin@2.15.1'
    },
    actions: [''],
    description: [''],
    keepDependencies: ['false'],
    properties: [
      [Object]
    ],
    scm: [
      [Object]
    ]
  }
}
```

when I'm trying too access

```
console.log(jason.maven2-moduleset.$.scm)
```

it's throwing following error

```
events.js:154
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

ReferenceError: moduleset is not defined
    at /NodeJS/configxml/configxml.js:20:62
    at Parser.<anonymous> (/NodeJS/configxml/node_modules/xml2js/lib/xml2js.js:489:18)
    at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
    at Parser.emit (events.js:182:7)
    at Object.onclosetag (/NodeJS/configxml/node_modules/xml2js/lib/xml2js.js:447:26)
    at emit (/NodeJS/configxml/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:640:35)
    at emitNode (/NodeJS/configxml/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:645:5)
    at closeTag (/NodeJS/configxml/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:905:7)
    at Object.write (/NodeJS/configxml/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:1452:13)
    at Parser.exports.Parser.Parser.parseString (/NodeJS/configxml/node_modules/xml2js/lib/xml2js.js:508:31)
```

I want to get data in 'scm' , Don't know where I'm doing wrong. Could tell me how to display data in scm object.

Comment: `scm` isn't a field on `$`. It is a sibling to it according to your object literal. Try `console.log(jason['maven2-moduleset'].scm)`

Comment: See how important reasonable indentation is? Even if you're working with "unformatted" JSON, you can still beautify it to help legibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues here, but not to worry as both are an easy fix.

**Issue 1 - You can't use the dot notation with keys with symbols**

Instead, you must use the `[]` with the name of the key as a string inside, e.g:

Invalid: `console.log(jason.maven2-moduleset)`

Valid: `console.log(jason['maven2-moduleset'])`

---

**Issue 2 - `scm` is not a property of `$`**

`$` only has one property, and it is `plugin`

---

**Solution**

This will work: `console.log(jason['maven2-moduleset'].scm)`

Comment: why dot notations is not valid can you brief ?

Comment: It's only not valid when you have symbols in the keyname, in this case it's because `-` in `maven2-moduleset` is also the minus operator.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you are trying to use dot notation with an invalid character (the dash). To fix this you should use array notation. EX. `jason['maven2-moduleset']['$']['scm']` either way it accesses the same values, it's just a slightly different format

> A JavaScript identifier must start with a letter, underscore (_), or dollar sign ($); subsequent characters can also be digits (0-9). Because JavaScript is case sensitive, letters include the characters "A" through "Z" (uppercase) and the characters "a" through "z" (lowercase).
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Variables

Comment: Was going to upvote this but ran out of votes: leaving this comment so I can upvote later

Comment: `scm` isn't under `$`, though.

Comment: your right, I left it in that order to stay truer to the request in the question. With what I have written you will get undefined but you wont get an error